# Azure Point-to-Site VPN but no DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn, azure

I've got:

- an Azure Virtual Network,
- an Windows Server 2012 Domain Controller on that network,
- a Point-to-Site VPN set up for that network all the way so that I can connect to it from my local machine and ping VM ip addresses
- a registered DNS Server of the Domain Controller
- a registered DNS Server for the Virtual Network (overriding the Azure Name Resolution, I guess)

But I **cannot resolve DNS names of VMs** in the network from a VPN-connected client.  Shouldn't this just work?  What might be wrong?

The advanced settings of my network adapters don't show this connection as something I can reorder to prioritize DNS.

The client is Windows 8.1, by the way.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the DNS setting of the client (i.e. your laptop that is connecting to the P2S VPN)?

Comment: The Azure VPN adapter doesn't give the traditional options for IP address and dns configuration.  But the main adapter is set to "obtain automatically".  Strangely, (and when connected) `ipconfig /all` doesn't show any adapter that I recognize as being the VPN!

Comment: I have a very similar setup. After connecting to the VPN I see a "PPP adapter" with a guid that matches the virtual network id. I cannot resolve the hostname of the Azure VMs, but the FQDN works (e.g. server1.domainname.com). This might be implied, but is the DNS server of your virtual network pointing to the Domain Controller? Also, have you verified your servers are registering themselves on the DNS server running on your Domain Controller?

Comment: FQDNs don't work either.  Yes, the DNS of the virtual network points to the dns/domain controller as registered in Azure.  The domain controller is the only VM - I'd like to join my laptop to that domain through the VPN which I think works fine but let me know otherwise.  I have a similar setup - same subscription, distinct Virtual Network, distinct domain, DC and member.  DNS works fine internally there and still fails over VPN (didn't have a need for that in that particular setup).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same problem: downloaded and installed the Azure Point-to-Site VPN, then no DNS servers. It  turned out that I had not registered DNS servers in the network until after the package was installed, and DNS servers are not dynamic for Azure VPN clients. Once the network is completely set up, THEN download the VPN package and it should work just fine.