# Can't resolve internal names over P2S,S2S in Azure

Tags: vpn, azure, internal-dns, timeout

For some reason, our DNS resolution does not work correctly over SSTP VPN or S2S connection in azure.

Everything works fine directly in the Azure environment. Additionally, I get the correct DNS servers when establishing SSTP connection but the resolution does not work, DNS requests just time out.

So what has been tested so far:

- configured P2S connection manually and forced the tunnel
- appended connection specific suffixes

Any ideas, what I should look into?

PPP adapter test:

```
Connection-specific DNS Suffix . :  test.internal
Description . . . . . . . . . . . : test
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.10.10.4(Preferred)
Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 168.63.129.16

NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Answer (score 0):

Fresh VPN connections on Windows client machines do use a static routing metric, that sets your default gateway (= default route) to the VPN endpoint. While that is *usually* correct, in this case your DNS (168.*) is on another network than your environment (10.*). The 168.* is most probably not transparently reachable through your VPN gateway.

You can fix this on the gateway (and routing) side of your environment, or let the client decide what to do. I would simply disable the "set as default gateway" option in the newly created VPN adapter (Properties > IPv4 > Properties > Enhanced > Set as default gateway #off).

You can also do this with PowerShell:

```
Set-VpnConnection "CONNECTION NAME" -SplitTunneling $true
```

To add other networks to your VPN route, use the Add-VpnConnectionRoute CMDlet:

```
Add-VpnConnectionRoute -ConnectionName "CONNECTION NAME" -DestinationPrefix 10.42.42.0/24
```

Additionally, your client will then use it's own Internet connection for internet activities and no longer pu everythin on your VPN.

Comment: Thanks for getting back, that's the case - by default split tunnel is enabled for connection, so I played around with different options.none of them works and that makes me confused.

Answer (score 0):

The [IP address 168.63.129.16](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/what-is-ip-address-168-63-129-16) is owned by MS. It's an Azure provided DNS server, in your scenario that [Resolution of Azure hostnames from on-premises computers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances).

> Forward queries to a customer-managed DNS proxy server in the
>   corresponding virtual network, the proxy server forwards queries to
>   Azure for resolution. See [Name resolution using your own DNS server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-name-resolution-for-vms-and-role-instances#name-resolution-that-uses-your-own-dns-server).

You could set up your [DNS server in your Azure virtual network](https://infra.engineer/azure/26-azure-point-to-site-client-vpn), after the VPN connection is updated, then download the VPN client packages.

For more information, you can view [a similar thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/562821/azure-point-to-site-vpn-but-no-dns).

Comment: That's the case, I need to rely on Azure provided DNS...